# NAS using samba not working: smbclient fails with error NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND

Tags: samba

I'm trying to set up a NAS using samba, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server), but when trying to "Test the Share Access" `smbclient` fails.

```
$ smbclient -U userName //SA/FSName
Password for [WORKGROUP\userName]:
do_connect: Connection to SA failed (Error NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND)
```

```
$ smbclient -L localhost
Password for [WORKGROUP\userName]:

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    FSName          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (computerName server (Samba, Ubuntu))
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

```
$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[FSName]
    inherit permissions = Yes
    path = /mnt/fsName/
    read only = No
```

```
$ ls -l /mnt/
total 4
drwxrws--- 3 root groupName 4096 Jun  9  2023 fsName
```

```
$ findmnt /mnt/fsName
TARGET         SOURCE     FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/fsName    /dev/md127 ext4   rw,relatime,discard,stripe=256
```

I don't know what SELinux is, but `semanage` isn't installed so I don't think that is the problem.

I've restarted the machine and server daemon since configuring everything.

I saw a share from the computer on a separate linux device after starting the server daemon the first time. However, I was never able to access it and am no longer seeing it.

```
$ samba --version
Version 4.15.13-Ubuntu
```

**Edit:**

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS

```
$ sudo ps aux | grep smbd
root        1882  0.0  0.0  86756 24320 ?        Ss   Jan30   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root        1884  0.0  0.0  84604 10156 ?        S    Jan30   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root        1885  0.0  0.0  84612  8108 ?        S    Jan30   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
userName   10100  0.0  0.0   9212  2432 pts/0    S+   18:24   0:00 grep --color=auto smbd
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend figured it out. Replace `//SA/FSName` with `//ComputerName/FSName` and it will work.

Maybe someone can provide a better answer and explain some of the details or provide resources to learn more about it. But if you just need it to work, this will do it.

Comment: I don't know how either one of those would work unless the host name of the server you are accessing is either "SA" or "ComputerName". The HowTo you reference apparently assumes the user knows how to address a share ( FSName ) located on a server ( SA ) and further assumes said user would replace those values with real ones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Morbius1 Yea, the only shares I've addressed used `//Share`, so I was a little confused by the (SA) and didn't make the connection to the structure `//Sever/Share`. I figured out replacing FSName, but I thought (SA) was some sort of abbreviation for Samba of share and didn't think to change it.